# TortoiseGit overlay icon missing from a single versioned file

Tags: tortoise-git

I've found a file in my project which has definitely been added and committed but which TortoiseGit hasn't added an overlay icon for and doesn't show most of the options I'd expect to see in the file's context menu. If I look at differences for the parent folder, I can see changes made to the file, but TortoiseGit only shows me the context menu for an unversioned file.

If I try to add the file again, TortoiseGit claims to have done it, but it still doesn't show the overlay icon or the appropriate menus. As far as I am aware, this is the only file that is affected in this way. I actually have two ongoing projects based on the same source code, and this file "unversioned" in both. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

The project is an ASP.NET MVC application in C# and the file is site.css, if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a casing issue (Git is case sensitive and TortoiseGit is, by default, too).

Check that the filename matches the filename in the Git index (e.g., you can delete the file and restore it using Git).

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2980